# Scudo Error in Android logfile during closing an App created with Delphi 10.4.1

Tags: android, delphi

I have created a Musicplayer App for Android (and Windows) for private usage in Delphi 10.4.1 which runs fine without any error messages. However: I discovered that in the logfile from Android I receive a SIGABRT error 'Scudo ERROR: invalid chunk state when deallocating address xxx' everytime the app is closed. No error message is visible from within the app or within the IDE.
I have no idea where to start to find the error. Any suggestions?

Here is an example of the error message in the logfile:

```
06-02 17:48:26.641 F/libc    ( 1748): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 1748 (cadero.MusicBox), pid 1748 (cadero.MusicBox)
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/...'
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): Revision: '5'
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): ABI: 'arm64'
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): Processor: '0'
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): Timestamp: 2022-06-02 17:48:26.810314587+0200
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): Process uptime: 3416s
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): Cmdline: com.embarcadero.MusicBox
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): pid: 1748, tid: 1748, name: cadero.MusicBox  >>> com.embarcadero.MusicBox <<<
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): uid: 10558
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): Abort message: 'Scudo ERROR: invalid chunk state when deallocating address 0x20000716f5a5fb0
06-02 17:48:27.953 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): '
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):     x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000006d4  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007fe80f02d0
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):     x4  0000000000808080  x5  0000000000808080  x6  0000000000808080  x7  8080800000000000
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  50e5665ba3ea522b  x10 0000000000000000  x11 ffffff80fffffbdf
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):     x12 0000000000000001  x13 000015c77efd3502  x14 00260f368244e36c  x15 0000000000000070
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):     x16 00000073dcc4a060  x17 00000073dcc26890  x18 0000007fe80ef808  x19 00000000000006d4
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):     x20 00000000000006d4  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000000  x23 b40000729f54e0c0
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):     x24 0000000070a925d8  x25 0000000000000003  x26 0000000000000069  x27 00000073e51e5000
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):     x28 000000712d217000  x29 0000007fe80f0350
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):     lr  00000073dcbd6a10  sp  0000007fe80f02b0  pc  00000073dcbd6a3c  pst 0000000000001000
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352): backtrace:
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #00 pc 0000000000051a3c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168) (BuildId: 2eccdd45647af1cc8350cd505ceb730b)
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #01 pc 000000000004165c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::die()+12) (BuildId: 2eccdd45647af1cc8350cd505ceb730b)
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #02 pc 0000000000041d74  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::ScopedErrorReport::~ScopedErrorReport()+36) (BuildId: 2eccdd45647af1cc8350cd505ceb730b)
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #03 pc 0000000000041fc8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::reportInvalidChunkState(scudo::AllocatorAction, void*)+80) (BuildId: 2eccdd45647af1cc8350cd505ceb730b)
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #04 pc 0000000000043654  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::deallocate(void*, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, unsigned long)+316) (BuildId: 2eccdd45647af1cc8350cd505ceb730b)
06-02 17:48:27.954 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #05 pc 0000000001185304  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #06 pc 00000000011842fc  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #07 pc 000000000117f52c  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #08 pc 00000000011a52b8  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #09 pc 00000000011866cc  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #10 pc 00000000011a451c  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #11 pc 000000000117f680  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #12 pc 000000000118c528  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #13 pc 0000000001185850  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #14 pc 0000000001185640  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #15 pc 000000000118c0f4  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #16 pc 000000000118c090  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #17 pc 0000000001186728  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #18 pc 000000000118d720  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #19 pc 000000000118c538  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #20 pc 0000000001185850  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.955 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #21 pc 000000000141e83c  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/lib/arm64/libMusicBox.so
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #22 pc 00000000000d5c54  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeCode::~NativeCode()+52) (BuildId: edc253edfe592db0b4e2bf94710d709d)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #23 pc 00000000000d53b4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::unloadNativeCode_native(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long)+32) (BuildId: edc253edfe592db0b4e2bf94710d709d)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #24 pc 00000000002743a4  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+100)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #25 pc 00000000002ca764  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #26 pc 00000000002ee6b0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+312) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #27 pc 000000000040ade4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+820) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #28 pc 0000000000409ce0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1580) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #29 pc 00000000002c4f94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #30 pc 0000000000251ea8  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.NativeActivity.onDestroy+64)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #31 pc 000000000027d840  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3351068054637636664)+644) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #32 pc 000000000035a9e4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+148) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #33 pc 000000000040b05c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1452) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #34 pc 00000000002ec494  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeSuper+3772) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #35 pc 00000000002c4f14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_super+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #36 pc 0000000000064276  /data/app/~~09NKSX_VIdCyNCpP8V7KSg==/com.embarcadero.MusicBox-Hlf3SdKPmfMhPE7KQqLtMQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity.onDestroy+0)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #37 pc 000000000027d840  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3351068054637636664)+644) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.956 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #38 pc 000000000035a9e4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+148) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #39 pc 000000000040b05c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1452) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #40 pc 00000000002c0ea4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+5380) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #41 pc 00000000002c4e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #42 pc 00000000001c4ad2  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Activity.performDestroy+102)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #43 pc 00000000002c0294  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2292) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #44 pc 00000000002c4e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #45 pc 00000000002484d4  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy+0)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #46 pc 00000000002bfcf4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+852) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #47 pc 00000000002c4e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #48 pc 00000000001bc7ec  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity+224)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #49 pc 000000000027d840  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3351068054637636664)+644) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #50 pc 000000000035a9e4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+148) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #51 pc 000000000035a2fc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+3020) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #52 pc 0000000000358600  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualRange+480) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #53 pc 00000000002c5194  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_range+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #54 pc 00000000001b94ec  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity+0)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #55 pc 000000000027d840  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3351068054637636664)+644) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.957 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #56 pc 000000000035a9e4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+148) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #57 pc 000000000035b048  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1032) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #58 pc 0000000000358978  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualRange+1368) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #59 pc 00000000002c5194  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_range+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #60 pc 00000000002ed9b8  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute+32)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #61 pc 00000000002c0294  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2292) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #62 pc 00000000002c4e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #63 pc 00000000002ecc88  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute+8)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #64 pc 00000000002c0294  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2292) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #65 pc 00000000002c4e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #66 pc 00000000002f0fbc  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState+64)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #67 pc 000000000040a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+3104) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #68 pc 00000000002c4f94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #69 pc 00000000002f0e64  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute+152)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #70 pc 00000000002c0294  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+2292) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #71 pc 00000000002c4e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #72 pc 00000000001b0ef8  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+276)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #73 pc 000000000027d840  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3351068054637636664)+644) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.958 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #74 pc 000000000027c9e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1176) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #75 pc 00000000002d4178  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #76 pc 000000000203c4d8  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+168)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #77 pc 000000000203cd40  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Looper.loopOnce+992)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #78 pc 000000000201fb60  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Looper.loop+464)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #79 pc 00000000002caa7c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_osr_stub+60) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #80 pc 0000000000779fb0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpMaybeDoOnStackReplacement+860) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #81 pc 00000000002c99d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpHelpers+240) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #82 pc 00000000004ca900  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.os.Looper.loop+160)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #83 pc 000000000076c840  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+620) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #84 pc 00000000002c5014  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #85 pc 00000000001bc586  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main+214)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #86 pc 000000000027d840  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3351068054637636664)+644) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #87 pc 000000000027c9e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1176) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #88 pc 00000000002d4178  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #89 pc 00000000002ca9e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #90 pc 000000000035b5d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (_jobject* art::InvokeMethod<(art::PointerSize)8>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+608) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.959 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #91 pc 000000000035b348  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #92 pc 00000000000b2f74  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+132) (BuildId: ad9ee401645a5135206a62ff86fc2ef5cdc29120)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #93 pc 00000000002ca764  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #94 pc 00000000002ee6b0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+312) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #95 pc 000000000040ade4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+820) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #96 pc 00000000002c0ea4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+5380) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #97 pc 00000000002c4e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #98 pc 00000000004598a2  /system/framework/framework.jar (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #99 pc 000000000027d840  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.3351068054637636664)+644) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #100 pc 000000000027c9e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1176) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #101 pc 00000000002d4178  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #102 pc 0000000000b437b8  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2376)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #103 pc 00000000002ca9e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #104 pc 000000000044ca04  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+464) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #105 pc 000000000062cf30  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+268) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #106 pc 00000000000b3bf8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124) (BuildId: edc253edfe592db0b4e2bf94710d709d)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #107 pc 00000000000c01e4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+852) (BuildId: edc253edfe592db0b4e2bf94710d709d)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #108 pc 00000000000025a8  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1360) (BuildId: 391e8f4ff82befde30d19b25efde721d)
06-02 17:48:27.960 F/DEBUG   ( 9352):       #109 pc 0000000000049f14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+100) (BuildId: 2eccdd45647af1cc8350cd505ceb730b)
```

Comment: [Scudo](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/scudo) seems to be a library that handles memory allocation and deallocation in Android in a secure way to prevent common memory based vulnerabilities. It is used since Android 11 and it looks like your Delphi version created code with a bug that triggers this protection. From my perspective this is a bug of Delphi and thus the only way to fix it is to contact Embarcadero (or install a version of Delphi that is newer and potentially has the fix already integrated).

Comment: At least this does not seem to be a general problem with Apps created with this version of Delphi, since other Apps do not show this behaviour.

Comment: It is possible that only certain Delphi code generates ARM64 code that triggers this problem. The it would be still a general problem but only affect certain apps that has this code.

Comment: Revisiting after some time: I had problems with this issue for a long time, even with a newer nersion of Delphi and not been really able to handle it. It is annoying since Android always complains about the program. I found out not really a solution, but a nasty workaround: Adding a "halt(0)" statement as last line of the formdestroy method supresses this error for me...